# Pushing err message to Toast for user feedback

Tags: javascript, react-native, clerk

I'm using Clerk for a React Native/Expo app, which is going great.  But, I'm having issues pushing exceptions to the user via a Toast message.

Using the standard Clerk code:

```js
const onPressVerify = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!isLoaded) {
    return;
  }

  try {
    const completeSignUp = await signUp.attemptEmailAddressVerification({
      code,
    });
    if (completeSignUp.status !== 'complete') {
      /*  investigate the response, to see if there was an error
         or if the user needs to complete more steps.*/
      console.log(JSON.stringify(completeSignUp, null, 2));
    }
    if (completeSignUp.status === 'complete') {
      await setActive({ session: completeSignUp.createdSessionId });
      router.push('/');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
  }
}
```

If Clerk fails, i.e. "password not long enough", "or could not find account", the catch (and console log) displays

```
 ERROR  [{
"code": "form_identifier_not_found",
"message": "Couldn't find your account.",
"longMessage": "Couldn't find your account.",
"meta": {
  "paramName": "identifier"
}}]
```

Question.  To use react-native-toast-message, how do I add 'message' to a Toast message as part of the catch?  Being an object, I'm struggling to understand the construct and requirement.

```
Toast.show({
    type: "error",
    text1: ????
  })
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To extract the `message` property from the ERROR object you can do:

```
 const errorMessage = err && err.message;
```

OR

```
 const errorMessage = err && err[0] && err[0].message;
```

Here, `err[0].message` is used to access the `message` property from the first element of the array(Error). This assumes that your ERROR object is always an array with at least one element and that the `message` property is present.

(This is based on the structure of the ERROR object you provided.

- and to display the error message in Toast:

```
Toast.show({
      type: "error",
      text1: errorMessage || "Error occurred",
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response and the learning experience for reading the array.  Very useful!  Have a great rest of your week - I will now this is working!

Comment: @Clarkie You are welcome! Great to hear that :-)